# Pyspark DataFrame - Convert a column with an array of n elements "key=value" to n new columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following Dataframe

```
+-------_--------------------------------------------+
| Col1                                               |
+------_---------------------------------------------+
|["field1=abc","field2=asd",....,"fieldN=zzz"]       |
|["field1=abc1","field2=asd1",....,"fieldN=zzz1"]    |  
|["field1=abc2","field2=asd2",....,"fieldN=zzz2"]    |  
| .................................................  |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

to this

```
+-------_--------------------------------------------+
| field1 | field2 | ....        | fieldN             |
+------_---------------------------------------------+
|abc     | asd    |....         | zzz                |
|abc1    | asd1   |....         | zzz1               |
|abc2    | asd2   |....         | zzz2               |
| .................................................  |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

I found some examples like

```
df=df.withColumn('name', F.col('exploded').getItem(0))
```

but since I have many fields I would prefer something more generic

Any idea?

Comment: Could you also post an example of the schema on your original DF?  It's unclear whether those are subfields or just a string of JSON data from the table print

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column is a struct type and not just a string of JSON data:

There are a couple of options.  You can use "field.*" in SQL to select all the subfields.  The easiest way to do this in python is with the `selectExpr` method on a DataFrame.  Note that you can also select other fields if you want to maintain them. 
 For example:

```
>>> data = [
    ((1, 2, 3, 4),),
    ((4, 5, 6, 7),)
]

>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(data))

>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- _1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _2: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _3: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _4: long (nullable = true)

>>> df.show()
+------------+
|          _1|
+------------+
|[1, 2, 3, 4]|
|[4, 5, 6, 7]|
+------------+


>>> df2 = df.selectExpr("_1 as original", "_1.*")
>>> df2.show()
+------------+---+---+---+---+
|    original| _1| _2| _3| _4|
+------------+---+---+---+---+
|[1, 2, 3, 4]|  1|  2|  3|  4|
|[4, 5, 6, 7]|  4|  5|  6|  7|
+------------+---+---+---+---+
```

Alternatively, the schema field on a DataFrame can be used to determine all the fields and their types, along with any subfields.  You could then use those names to loop over them and use `withColumn` like you did above.  For example:

```
>>> struct_field = next(f for f in df.schema if f.name == "_1")
>>> subfield_names = [f.name for f in struct_field.dataType.fields]
>>> print subfield_names
['_1', '_2', '_3', '_4']
```